# play 2.4 error: error in sideband demultiplexer open shift

Tags: git, openshift

The git push step on a [Openshift rhcloud platform](https://www.openshift.com/products) seems to fail:

```
remote: [info] Wrote /var/lib/openshift/55d30c940c1e661be9000177/app-
root/runtime/repo/target/scala-2.11/add2cal_2.11-1.0.0.pom

remote: [info] Main Scala API documentation to /var/lib/openshift/55d30c940c1e661be9000177/app-root/runtime/repo/target/scala-2.11/api...

remote: [info] Compiling 24 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /var/lib/openshift/55d30c940c1e661be9000177/app-root/runtime/repo/target/scala-2.11/classes...

remote: [info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.11.6. Compiling...

remote: [info] Packaging /var/lib/openshift/55d30c940c1e661be9000177/app-root/runtime/repo/target/scala-2.11/add2cal_2.11-1.0.0-web-assets.jar ...

remote: [info] Done packaging.

Connection to add2cal-pamu.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

error: error in sideband demultiplexer

To ssh://55d30c940c1e661be9000177@add2cal-pamu.rhcloud.com/~/git/add2cal.git/
   4223625..474341c  master -> master

error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://55d30c940c1e661be9000177@add2cal-pamu.rhcloud.com/~/git/add2cal.git/'
```

How to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 1):

[openshift.redhat.com status](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/status) reports the application of security updates to JBoss gears.

That could have a side effect on some instances.
See [this issue](https://github.com/Athou/commafeed/issues/637):

> since I started digging on this I've been intermittently failing and succeeding in deploying it on a small gear (actually more failures than successes). Works fine in a medium.

It could be an issue with the [gear size](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202300984-Are-there-different-gear-sizes-and-how-much-do-they-cost-) and its 1GB storage space.

Comment: any fix available. when will the system behave normally.

Comment: @pamu that I don't know. OpenShift support (https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us) might help here.